Why add eggs to semolina dough one hot, one cold?
On a packet of durum semolina that I bought is a recipe for Nocken (a light Austrian dumpling). It has you mix the semolina into boiling milk, which gets pretty stiff as the liquid is taken up; then off the heat, mix in one egg; then let cool and add the second egg.
When I did this, I half expected the first egg would begin to set on the hot paste. It didn't, and actually I had stirred the semolina in already off the hob. But I don't think it's supposed to set either, that wouldn't give a smooth mix. So why not add both eggs early, or add them both after cooling?
My guess would be that perhaps in the late case the dough would be too thin from the eggs' water. And similarly, in the early case the dough might become too stiff to work, or too dense for the target texture, when all the eggs' water is up for absorption. On the other hand, I didn't feel that the dough had gotten much stiffer after cooling with the one egg, and anyway if that were the hazard one could form the dumplings while still warm. (Right?)
What does the described mixing schedule achieve?
Edit: Customer service, whom I also asked this, is not responding. Who knows how they got by the recipes to put on the box. Full instructions are:
Bring to boil 250ml milk with 20g butter, 1tsp salt.
Add 100g durum semolina and stir until dough lifts off pot bottom.
Remove from heat, stir in one egg, and let cool.
Then stir in second egg.
Form dumplings with two teaspoons and cook in chicken broth for 10min.

I've asked customer service about it, response pending.

If you still want an answer after that, you'll need to share the actual recipe.

I propose a little science experiment. Divide the mixture in half after the first two steps. Each half now needs one egg. In the first half, add the egg while still hot. In the second, half cool completely before adding the egg. Cook up the dumplings and observe the difference if any!

From the Nocken recipes I could find only about 10% use this method of adding one egg to the cold dough. Coincidentally those are recipes where Nocken are meant to be placed in broth afterwards, take that as you may

@npst I wouldn't know what to take from that observation, are you saying you neither?

Indeed, other than the two-step-egg seems not to be necessary
